# How do I show that $\kappa^+ \le 2^\kappa$ for every cardinal $\kappa$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I'm looking into using $2^\kappa = \kappa^\kappa$ to prove this because it follows from $2 < \kappa < \kappa^+$ but I'm not sure how to connect the two together. Anyway, this might not even be the right approach to this problem.

Only a hint on how to show this is true - if not a complete proof - would also be great. I'm just asking out of curiosity, by the way. This isn't my homework.

Comment: It would help to know just what you've learned about this stuff. You know that $2^{\kappa}\gt\kappa$? You know that all cardinals are comparable, so that for any $\lambda$ either $\lambda\ge\kappa^+$ or else $\lambda\lt\kappa^+$? You know that $\lambda\lt\kappa^+$ implies $\lambda\le\kappa$?

Comment: @bof Yes I know Cantor's theorem. And all the cardinals are comparable only when you assume AC. I haven't seen a proof of $\lambda < \kappa^+$ implies $\lambda \le \kappa$. I'll look into that. I think it's best to assume I know everything, and answer me. I'd ask if I didn't understand something.

Comment: You **are** assuming AC, aren't you? You can't prove $\aleph_1\le2^{\aleph_0}$ without AC.

Comment: @bof Yes, assuming AC.

Comment: @Mark if you assume AC, $\kappa^{+} \leq 2^\kappa$ is immediate because $<$ is a total order on ordinals and by definition $k^{+}$ is the immediate successor of $\kappa$ for that order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In $\sf ZFC$ one can argue that since every two cardinals are comparable, either $\kappa^+\leq2^\kappa$, or $2^\kappa\leq\kappa^+$. However from Cantor's theorem $\kappa<2^\kappa$, and by definition we have $\kappa<\lambda\rightarrow\kappa^+\leq\lambda$, and this gives us the wanted proof. But we can prove some part of this without the axiom of choice, and then only use the axiom of choice for the final punch. Here are the details.

---

This is a combination of the following two theorems. One using the axiom of choice, and another not.

> **Theorem. ($\sf ZF$)** Suppose that $\kappa$ is a well-ordered cardinal, then there exists a surjection from $2^\kappa$ onto $\kappa^+$.

*Proof.* Note that $\kappa$ is equipotent with $\kappa\times\kappa$ (without an appeal to the axiom of choice, this is proved from the definition of Hessenberg sums for ordinals). We define the following map $\pi\colon\mathcal P(\kappa\times\kappa)\to\kappa^+$: $$\pi(A)=\begin{cases}\alpha & A\text{ is a well-ordering of its domain, and its order type is }\alpha\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Since every ordinal $\alpha<\kappa^+$ can be mapped into $\kappa$, we have that every $\alpha<\kappa^+$ appears in the range of $\pi$, and therefore this is a surjection, as wanted. $\square$

Now to the part where the axiom of choice is invoked.

> **Theorem. ($\sf ZFC$)** Every surjection admits an injective inverse.

*Proof.* Suppose $f\colon A\to B$ is a surjection, then $\{f^{-1}(b)\mid b\in B\}$ is a family of non-empty sets. From the axiom of choice it follows that there is a function $g\colon B\to A$ such that $g(b)\in f^{-1}(b)$, as wanted. $\square$

---

> **Corollary. ($\sf ZFC$)** If $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then $\kappa^+\leq2^\kappa$.

*Proof.* There exists a surjection from $2^\kappa$ onto $\kappa^+$, and therefore an injection from $\kappa^+$ into $2^\kappa$. $\square$

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: By Hessenberg sums for ordinals do you mean the canonical well-ordering of ordinal pairs? Used to prove that $\aleph_\alpha \times \aleph_\alpha = \aleph_\alpha$? And does not $|\kappa \times \kappa|=|\kappa|$ imply AC? Your first theorem seems also to be that of ZFC to me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Mark, you are correct. On all things. The Hessenberg sums are used to prove that $\aleph_\alpha\times\aleph_\alpha=\aleph_\alpha$, and $|A\times A|=|A|$ *for every infinite $A$* implies the axiom of choice; and every theorem of $\sf ZF$ is a theorem of $\sf ZFC$. The only fine point is that in $\sf ZF$ it is true for every **well-orderable set**, $|A\times A|=|A|$. But not every $A$ can be well-ordered, which is where the counterexamples live.

Comment: I see we're talking just about the ordinals. Only when $|A \times A|=|A|$ for all infinite sets then that imply AC. And I know if it's a theorem of ZF that makes it a theorem of ZFC also. I didn't phrase my comment very well. What I meant to say earlier was that your first theorem looked to be that of ZFC and not ZF.

Comment: Ah, yes. But note that the case in the first theorem is that $\kappa$ being an ordinal. So it's fine. It's a delicate point, though, and it's easy to miss at first.

Comment: Right. So thanks again for all your help. Cheers. :)

Comment: You're welcome!